# Disadvantages of condensing .cpp files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When compiling a 'static library' project in MSVC++, I often get .lib files that are several MB in size. If I use conditional macros and include directives to "condense" all my .cpp files in one .cpp file at compile time, the .lib file size decreases *considerably*.

Are there any disadvantages with this practice?

Comment: What is the problem with the lib files? Running out of disk space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem of *Unity Builds* as they are called is that they break the way C++ works.

In C++, a source file, with its includes preprocessed, is called a Translation Unit. Some symbols are "private" to this translation unit:

- symbols declared `static` at namespace level
- anything declared in anonymous namespace

If you *merge* several C++ files, then the compiler will *share* those *private* symbols among all the files that are merged together since from its point of view this has become a *single* Translation Unit.

You will get an error if two local classes suddenly have the same name, and idem for constants. Annoying as hell, but at least you are notified.

For functions however, it may break silently because of **overload**. When before the compiler would pick `static void launch(short u);` for your call to `launch(1)`, then suddenly it will shift to `static void launch(int i, Target t = "Irak");`. **Oups ?**

*Unity Builds* are dangerous. What you are looking for is called **WPO** (Whole Program Optimization) or **LTO** (Link Time Optimization), look into the innards of your compiler manual to know how to activate it.

Comment: Best answer so far, thanks! However WPO does not help with .lib file size. Actually I've always been using it (it's /GL in MSVC++).

Comment: That's because you don't link the library file (just "archiving" the object files). Linking happens when you create the final, executable code (exe or dll).

Answer (score 4):

A disadvantage would be if you change a single line in the cpp you have to compile the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

Your file might get more complex and you'll have to recompile everyting even if you just change one single source file. Other then that, there's no real disadvantage, unless the files are redefining local functions or variables that might screw you up, when merging everything (e.g. due to multiple definitions within one translation unit).

The size decrease you notice is due to advanced optimizations that become available that way (e.g. reusing more code). Depending on your code you might get similar results by enabling all optimizations for size as well as link time optimizations, which might result in some acceptable solution between both approaches.

Comment: There's no need to recompile *everything* if something changed. Unity builds can be reserved for release only, you don't have to use them all the time.

Comment: Yeah, sure, you can make it selective. But even then, you have to rebuild everything (even if it's for release builds only).

Comment: And for release you often want to perform a clean build anyway, to make sure no stale code gets linked in. So you'd rebuild the world anyway, and with unity builds it's often faster than with standard builds.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a confusing practice to include cpp to another cpp (at least you should leave explanatory comment about why did you do this).